# Solve $\sqrt{3}\cos2\theta+\sin2\theta-1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried using the identities $\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$ and $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$. These give

$\sqrt{3}(1-2\sin^2\theta)+2\sin\theta\cos\theta-1=0$

which doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Perhaps I must equate the function to something like $R\sin(2\theta+\alpha)$?

Comment: Why do you wish to use these identities? Can't you start solving in $\alpha$ by stating $\alpha=2\theta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{3}\cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta = 2\sin(2\theta+\pi/3)$

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you only use one identity:
$$\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1-\sin^2 2\theta}+\sin 2\theta=1$$
Write $t=\sin 2\theta$ to get:
$$3(1-t^2)=(1-t)^2$$
Which is just a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an equation of the form
$$
a\sin^2\theta+b\sin\theta\cos\theta+c\cos^2\theta+d=0
$$
you can use $1=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$ and write the equation as
$$
(a+d)\sin^2\theta+b\sin\theta\cos\theta+(c+d)\cos^2\theta=0
$$
If $a+d=0$, this factors; otherwise $\cos\theta=0$ is not a solution and so you can transform it into
$$
(a+d)\tan^2\theta+b\tan\theta+(c+d)=0
$$
that's quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can write:
\begin{align}
a\cos\theta+b\cos\theta&=
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(
  \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos\theta+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin\theta
\right)\\[2ex]
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\sin\alpha\cos\theta+\cos\alpha\sin\theta)
\end{align}

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Panda, the whole point of LaTeX formatting is so that you do not need to copy and paste images, and moreover answers are then searchable.

Comment: Also, the formula is clearly incorrect - what happens when $a>1$?

Comment: I added the missing factor (you seemed to have forgotten it) and translated into MathJax.

Comment: @nbubis:suppose a=10000,b=1 which sentence is wrong a/(...) is always under 1 so this is always true.

Comment: @Panda - with egreg's correction, this is now correct.